# JIRA API and jira4r gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jira

I would like to create an issue by jira4r gem and attach it to special components. I use code as you see below.

```
jira = Jira4R::JiraTool.new(2, "http://example.com/jira/")
jira.login("robot", "robot")

issue = Jira4R::V2::RemoteIssue.new
issue.project = "ABC"
issue.type = "1"
issue.components = ['10000']
issue.summary = "Do somethigs"
issue.assignee = -1
jira.createIssue(issue)
```

but there is a problem that it return an error

> SOAP::FaultError java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: array element type mismatch
>   and it is caused by setting "components"

Do you have some ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yay! I found the solution, mb it helps someone

```
component = Jira4R::V2::RemoteComponent.new(10010)
componentlist = Jira4R::V2::ArrayOf_tns1_RemoteComponent.new.push(component)

issue.components = componentlist
```

Answer (score 1):

According to http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+SOAP+Client you need remote component instead of component id.

Smth like

```
issue.components = [Jira4R::V2::RemoteComponent.new('10000')]
```

Comment: no, unfortunately it doesn't work, it just create an empty component object and try to pass it, but issue couldn't be created.